# Can I siege/take county that is under the control of a revolt?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So Norway is defending itself from an internal revolt that has taken over several provinces including Cornwall. I have a De Jure claim on it, but it is currently taken over by the revolt (when I click on the county, the revolt coat of arms is shown in between the castle/city/bishopric ones - and it has the usual striped colours on the map).

So my question is (because I am playing Ironman, don't want to risk doing something stupid):

Can I declare war on Norway for Cornwall and actually siege and take it, or will the game only allow me to do that once the revolt is crushed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. And the siege would be easier because of depleted garrison.

But if the revolt is about getting independent, and the rebels win, and the owner of the province changes, then your war will be canceled and you will have to declare it again on the new owner.

Comment: This should only be possible when it is occupied by a legit rebel faction (red and black coat of arms), not by a NPC vassal faction rebelling against their liege. It seems from the OPs question that it is indeed regular rebels, so I agree, he should be able to siege it.

Comment: Yes that's correct, red and black.